# Usage of "danwei" in english

Tags: translation

Is the term "danwei" singular or plural?  Ie, if there are several, is it several danweis or several danwei?

Comment: I'm afraid this is rather a question for the English Language Stackexchange site. Actually, Chinese nouns have no plural forms, so the English language literature prefers 'danwei' as plural form.

Comment: What is "danwei"? Do you mean `单位`?

Comment: @Stan, probably. I don't think any other 'danwei' has made it into the English language, so we can assume he is asking about 'work unit' 单位.

Comment: @DrunkenMaster I just wonder why the OP doesn't simply adopt the word "unit" in English -- it's already a perfect equivalent of 单位.

Comment: @Stan True. However, 'work unit' and 'danwei' are both used in English to refer to the Chinese term 单位.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I will use the term danwei as either singular or plural in english.

Comment: Though "danwei" can be translated into "unit", the romanized term is still used in some context (ex. sociological discussion) to refer a specific concept in Chinese culture. A similar case is "guanxi" and "relationship".

Answer (score 2):

looks through Google Books and what not comes up with a few instances of **danweis**:

**From Family to Market: Labor Allocation in Contemporary China**

> This danwei-based income discrepancy worsened drastically during the reform years as the danweis acquired more autonomous authority in allocating financial

**Globalisation and the Chinese City**

> Similarly, 'commercial land' refers to the lots occupied by the danweis under the administration of the financial or commercial system (Huang 1997).

**上海新城: 追寻蔓延都市里的社区和身份**

> Danweis ('danwei' literally means 'work unit') were cooperative or state-run companies whose members lived and worked communally, and often practiced one ...

**The Chinese Dream: A Society Under Construction**

> 15 The new Constitution banned all land transactions and land was allocated to danweis* free of charge.

I would totally go with a pluralized *danweis* for multiple danweis.